# How to get the price of a product for each store view?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created a custom tab in the product admin.

I have multiple input fields there and I want the values of them to be the price of the product for each store view.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
$storeID = Mage::app()->getStore($eachStore)->getId();

Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeID)->load($id)->getPrice();
```

This is how to do it:)

Note: I am using a `foreach` loop to get every store I have, hence the `$eachStore`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in a broader scope is to load collections if you dont need the information as a single piece of code.

You can do it like this:

```
$allStores = Mage::app()->getStores();
foreach($allStores as $store){
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter($store->getId())
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    foreach($collection as $_product) {
        echo $_product->getPrice();
    }
}
```